# Data filter works with json data but not with csv data

Tags: d3.js, vega, vega-lite

In [this](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/edge-bundling/) vega chart, if I download and convert the `flare-dependencies.json` to csv using the following `jq` command,

```
jq -r '(map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols | map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.])) as $rows | $cols, $rows[] | @csv' flare-dependencies.json > flare-dependencies.csv
```

And change the corresponding data property in the `edge-bundling.vg.json` file from:

```
{
  "name": "dependencies",
  "url": "data/flare-dependencies.json",
  "transform": [
    {
      "type": "formula",
      "expr": "treePath('tree', datum.source, datum.target)",
      "as": "treepath",
      "initonly": true
    }
  ]
},
```

to

```
{
  "name": "dependencies",
  "url": "data/flare-dependencies.csv",
  "format": { "type": "csv" },
  "transform": [
    {
      "type": "formula",
      "expr": "treePath('tree', datum.source, datum.target)",
      "as": "treepath",
      "initonly": true
    }
  ]
},
```

The hovering effect wont work(the colors wont change when I hover edges/nodes.

I suspect that the issue is with this section:

```
  "name": "selected",
  "source": "dependencies",
  "transform": [
    {
      "type": "filter",
      "expr": "datum.source === active || datum.target === active"
    }
  ]
```

What am I missing? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON data is typed; that is, the file format distinguishes between string and numerical data. CSV data is untyped: all entries are expressed as strings.

The chart specification above requires some fields to be numerical. When you convert the input data to CSV, you must add a [format](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/data/#format) specifier to specify numerical types for the numerical data columns.

In case of this chart you can use the following for the nodes data:

```
"format": {
  "type": "tsv",
  "parse": { "id": "number", "name": "string", "parent": "number" }
},
```

And the following for the links data:

```
"format": {
  "type": "tsv",
  "parse": { "source": "number", "target": "number" }
},
```